# If marginal probabilities equal, can we say anything about joint distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

Consider I have equal marginal probabilities as per:
$$p_{\theta}(x) = p_{\alpha}(x).$$
Now assume we know there exists another random variable $z$ that is of interest to us. Am  I correct in thinking that I can not deduce that:
$$p_{\theta}(x, z) = p_{\alpha}(x, z)?$$
I believe this would be the case because you can get the same marginal from different joint distributions, but I am unsure if that applies here.

Comment: Your final point applies here

Comment: As a warning, you can even have $X$ and $Z$ uncorrelated with various different joint distributions without changing their marginal distributions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. For example, suppose we have two bivariate normals. In the first, both $x$ and $z$ have mean 0 and variance 1, and correlation 0 (i.e. they are independent). In the second, both $x$ and $z$ still have mean 0 and variance 1, but their correlation is 0.5 (they are not independent). In both cases, the marginal distribution of $x$ will be normal with mean 0 and variance 1, but the joint distribution of $(x,z)$ will be different due to the different correlation values.

Comment: Thanks that's very clear and easy so have accepted as the answer.

Comment: if the marginals have 0 correlation, then they are independent, what does this say about the joint distribution in that case, compared to the case of 0.5 correlation?

Comment: If x and z are independent, then we can say that p(x,z) factors as p(x)p(z), but this would not be the case if there were 0.5 correlation.

Comment: If $x$ and $z$ are independent then the density ratio $\frac{p(x,z)}{p(x)p(z)}=1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, assuming non-zero p(x) and p(z). Or we could just write p(x,z) = p(x)p(z).

Comment: but if, on the other hand, they had a correlation of 0.5, then is $\frac{p(x,z)}{p(x)p(z)}>1$? or is $\frac{p(x,z)}{p(x)p(z)}<1$? How about if correlation were -0.5?

Answer (score 1):

The restrictions on marginals implies some restriction on the joint, namely

$$\sum_z p_\theta(x, z)  = \sum_z p_\alpha(x, z)$$

This is exactly one degrees of freedom, meaning that if you fix the all $n$ components of $p_\theta(x, z) $, then you are at liberty to choose $n-1$ element for $p_\alpha(x, z) $ anyway you want, with the last degree of freedom fixed by

$$p_\alpha(x, z_n) = \sum_z p_\theta(x, z) - \sum_{z\neq z_n} p_\alpha(x, z)$$.

This might be a small constraint or a relatively large one when the support in the $z$ dimension is a small set, think n=3 or n=2!

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting alternative way to think about it!